# Bound for sum of multiplicative character calculated over multivariate polynomial

Tags: finite-fields, exponential-sums

Let $f \in \mathbb{F}_q[x_1, \dots, x_k]$ be a polynomial with $\deg f = n$, and let $\chi$ be a multiplicative character over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Is there any known bound, possibly with conditions about $f$ and $\chi$, for
$$\left|\sum_{c_1, \dots, c_k \in \mathbb{F}_q} \chi(f(c_1, \dots, c_k)) \right| ?$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are several known bounds. The following statement, due to Katz, has quite strict conditions on $f$, but gives a very strong result. It is perhaps the simplest statement that gives such a strong bound.

Suppose that the equation $f=0$ defines a nonsingular hypersurface in $\mathbb A^k$, and the degree $n$ part of $f$ defines a nonsingular hypersurface in $\mathbb P^{k-1}$. Suppose also that either $n$ is prime to $q$ or $\chi^n$ is trivial.

Then $$\left|\sum_{c_1, \dots, c_k \in \mathbb{F}_q} \chi(f(c_1, \dots, c_k)) \right|  \leq (n-1)^k q^{k/2} $$

This is the main theorem of [Estimates for nonsingular multiplicative character sums](https://doi.org/10.1155/S1073792802106088) by Nick Katz.

Comment: Is there a keyword (I would have guessed multivariate Weil sums, but that doesn't seem to be in use) that is useful for looking up the literature on sums of this type?

Comment: @AnuragSahay I don't know one other than "exponential sums". Another paper to look at is Estimates for Singular Multiplicative Character Sums by Antonio Rojas-León. https://doi.org/10.1155/IMRN.2005.1221

Comment: thanks for the reference!